# How to call the Google cloudcommerceprocurement API using the Node API

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

We've got to approve a google marketplace purchase using the google marketplace account ID. We're succeeding in doing it in python, but it needs to happen in Node.

I've got the following python code that works, and I'm hoping to perform the same steps in node:

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
import google.auth
from google.auth import impersonated_credentials

PROCUREMENT_API = "cloudcommerceprocurement"


def main():
    # load default credentials
    credentials, _ = google.auth.default()

    # impersonate service account
    target_credentials = impersonated_credentials.Credentials(
        source_credentials=credentials,
        target_principal="<service_account_email_that_we_want_to_impersonate>",
        target_scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
        lifetime=500,
    )

    service = build(
        PROCUREMENT_API, "v1", cache_discovery=False, credentials=target_credentials
    )
    res = (
        service.providers()
        .accounts()
        .list(parent="providers/<provider_id>")
        .execute()
    )
    print(res)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And I am at a loss, one, node is not my language of choice. We only need to perform this action once per day at most, so speed is not massively important. We know we have permissions and serviceaccount etc. sorted, this is purely a "how to do in node" issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python code is performing the following

1. Google default auth
2. Build the procuremnt client based on google discovery file https://cloudcommerceprocurement.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1
3. Access the API to get the account list

With Nodejs you can do the following

1. First download the https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client
2. Build procurment client using

```
cd to cloned repo
npm i
npm run compile
node ./build/src/generator/generator.js 'https://cloudcommerceprocurement.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1'
```

3. Navigate to google-api-nodejs-client/src/apis/cloudcommerceprocurement/
4. npm pack
5. Now you can move tar ball to you project repo
6. pnpm add ./googleapis-cloudcommerceprocurement-0.1.0.tgz
7. Import procueremnt client similar to other google api and authenticate and access the rest api

Import client and types

```
import { cloudcommerceprocurement, auth } from "@googleapis/cloudcommerceprocurement";
import type { cloudcommerceprocurement_v1 } from "@googleapis/cloudcommerceprocurement";
```

Create auth and remember to replace YOUR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEYFILE

```
const googleAuth = new auth.GoogleAuth({
  YOUR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEYFILE,
  scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
});
```

Create Procuremnt client with above created googleAuth

```
const procurementClient = cloudcommerceprocurement({
  version: "v1",
  auth: googleAuth,
});
```

Call Rest API and remember replace YOUR_PARTNER_ID

```
const getAccountList = (): Promise<any> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    procurementClient.providers.accounts
      .list({ parent: 'providers/YOUR_PARTNER_ID' })
      .then(({ data }) => {
        console.log(data)
        resolve(data);
      })
      .catch((err: any) => {
        console.log(error)
        reject(err);
      });
  });
};

getAccountList()
```

Similar approach you can do for any missing client from google api's using discovery file